# Не выводятся html и значения в echo. Как исправить?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Появилась проблема после смены хостинга. На старом всё отображалось отлично. На новом только пустое место.
Есть код:

```html
<?php
require_once 'MAnkZEluQhvFp2VXVBO7GaqvIPa3w7F1.php';
  $link = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $password, $database);
  if (!$link) {
    echo 'Не могу соединиться с БД. Код ошибки: ' . mysqli_connect_errno() . ', ошибка: ' . mysqli_connect_error();
    exit;
  }
 global $wpdb;
 $cur_user = wp_get_current_user()->user_login;
 $cur_id = get_current_user_id();
 $now = time();
 
 $sql = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT o.create_date, o.uid, o.status, o.amount_value, o.lid, u.id, sum(r.amount) AS referrals_amount FROM uvbvn_users AS u INNER JOIN uvbvn_ihc_orders AS o ON o.uid = u.id INNER JOIN uvbvn_uap_affiliates AS a ON a.uid = u.id INNER JOIN uvbvn_uap_referrals AS r ON r.affiliate_id = a.id WHERE o.status = 'Completed' AND r.status = '2' GROUP BY r.affiliate_id, o.create_date, o.amount_value, o.lid");
 
  while ($result = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) {
     $start=($result['create_date']);
     $nstart=date("d.m.Y H:m", strtotime($start));
     $user_uid=($result['uid']);
     $user_id=($result['id']);
     $stat=($result['status']);
     $reg_lid=($result['lid']);
     $amount=($result['amount_value']); 
     $datediff = (strtotime("now") + (8 * 3600) - strtotime($result['create_date']))/ 86400;
     $datediff = floor($datediff);
     
   $referrals_amount=($result['referrals_amount']); 
   
      
   if ($user_uid==$cur_id&&($reg_lid==1 or $reg_lid==4 or $reg_lid==5 or $reg_lid==13 or $reg_lid==6)) {
  /* Начисляем процент */  
   $proc = 28;  //Процентов за всё время
      $proc_d =0.28*$datediff;  //Процентов в день
   $proc = ($amount+$referrals_amount)/100*$proc;  // высчитываем процент от числа
   $proc_d = ($amount+$referrals_amount)/100*$proc_d;  // высчитываем процент в день от числа
    $amount_all = $referrals_amount + $proc_d;
   $amountWithPct_all = $amount + $referrals_amount + $proc; // суммируем число с процентами от этого числа
   $amountWithPct_d = $amount + $referrals_amount + $proc_d; // суммируем число с процентами в день от этого числа
   round ($amountWithPct_all); // округляем
   round ($amountWithPct_d); // округляем
    
 echo   '<div class="uap-row"><div class="uap-user-page-nstart" style="padding-bottom:10px">Начало работы: ' . $nstart . '</div>
  <div class="uapcol-md-4 uap-account-overview-tab1">
   <div class="uap-account-no-box" style="padding-left:0px;">
    <div class="uap-account-no-box-inside">
      <div class="uap-count"> ' . $datediff . ' </div>
    <div class="uap-detail">Прошло дней</div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="uapcol-md-4 uap-account-overview-tab2">
   <div class="uap-account-no-box" style="padding-left:0px;">
    <div class="uap-account-no-box-inside">
      <div class="uap-count"> '. round($amount, 2) .' ₽</div>
    <div class="uap-detail">Внесено</div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="uapcol-md-4 uap-account-overview-tab3">
   <div class="uap-account-no-box" style="padding-left:0px;">
    <div class="uap-account-no-box-inside">
      <div class="uap-count"> '. round($referrals_amount, 2) .' ₽</div>
    <div class="uap-detail">Бонусы</div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="uapcol-md-4 uap-account-overview-tab4">
   <div class="uap-account-no-box uap-account-box-blue " style="padding-left:0px;">
    <div class="uap-account-no-box-inside">
      <div class="uap-count"> '. round($proc_d, 2) .' ₽</div>
    <div class="uap-detail">Проценты</div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
</div>

</div>
<div class="uap-row">
 <div class="uapcol-md-2 uap-account-overview-tab5">
   <div class="uap-account-no-box uap-account-box-green">
    <div class="uap-account-no-box-inside">
      <div class="uap-count">'. round($amount_all, 2) .' ₽</div>
    <div class="uap-detail">Бонусы + %</div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="uapcol-md-2 uap-account-overview-tab6">
   <div class="uap-account-no-box uap-account-box-red">
    <div class="uap-account-no-box-inside">
      <div class="uap-count"> '. round($amountWithPct_all, 2) .' ₽</div>
    <div class="uap-detail">Сумма на конец периода</div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
</div>';  
    
   }
  else{ /*echo   'Ничего не найдено';*/
    }   
  } 
?>
```

Версия PHP: 7.2.24(alt) Режим работы PHP: FastCGI (Apache)

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это исправить?

Comment: Для начала включите отображение ошибок, а там ясно будет. Видимо что-то не подтягивается..

Comment: и попробуйте раскомментировать строку /*echo 'Ничего не найдено';*/ - может действительно ничего не найдено?

Comment: @Yakoffka Строку раскомментировала. Выводит "Ничего не найдено". Но в базе же есть данные. Смотрю старых пользователей у них всё выводится. У новых с нового хостинга уже пустое место. Что-то я совсем запуталась. Где может быть проблема...

Comment: Проверьте, действительно-ли в базе данных, к которой Вы подключаетесь действительно есть ожидаемые Вами данные. Может идет подключение к другой базе?

Comment: @Yakoffka Точно к нужной базе подключаюсь. Других нет. Если бы не было подключения, то ошибку бы выдало. Данные тоже есть. Не понятно это всё.

Answer (score 1):

Гляньте, что находится в $sql после получения для старых и для новых пользователей:

```
var_dump($sql);
var_dump(mysqli_fetch_array($sql));
```

Сверьте типы и наличие данных в базе для старых и для новых пользователей,
и на всякий случай сверьте версии php на старом и новом хостингах.

Answer (score 0):

Проблема оказалась в этой строке `if ($user_uid==$cur_id&&($reg_lid==1 or $reg_lid==4 or $reg_lid==5 or $reg_lid==13 or $reg_lid==6))`
Надо было заменить or на OR и всё заработало.
Спасибо за помощь Yakoffka!

Comment: да я же того на этого.. просто мычал)) ты сама все решила!